# making subplots including a barchart

Tags: python, bar-chart, subplot

I want to plot 3 subplots, with the first plot as a bar. When i do this the x axis moves to left. And i get very strange looking barchart, see figure below. If i change ''bar'' by ''plot'' than it works fine, but the graph is a line instead of bars.

[image]

```
kwargs=dict(delimiter='\t',\
        skip_header=0,\
        missing_values='NaN',\
        converters={0:matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')},\
        dtype = float,\
        names=True,\
        )

storm_dis_cats = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\ker\Documents\Discharge_data_Catsop_27-06-2014.txt',**kwargs)

kwargs=dict(delimiter='\t',\
        skip_header=0,\
        missing_values='NaN',\
        converters={0:matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')},\
        dtype = float,\
        names=True,\
        )

storm_stage_cats = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\ker\Documents\Stageheight_data_Catsop_27-06-2014.txt',**kwargs)

kwargs=dict(delimiter='\t',\
        skip_header=0,\
        missing_values='NaN',\
        converters={0:matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')},\
        dtype = float,\
        names=True,\
        )

storm_rain_cats = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\ker\Documents\Rainfall_data_Catsop_27-06-2014.txt',**kwargs)

discharge = storm_dis_cats['discharge']
date = storm_stage_cats['date']
stage = storm_stage_cats['stage'] - 79.331
date_stage = storm_stage_cats['date']
rainfall = storm_rain_cats['rainfall']
date_rainfall = storm_rain_cats['date']

#set locator and formatter

hours    = matplotlib.dates.HourLocator()   # every year
months   = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()  # every month
hoursFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H')

#create plot

fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(311)
ax.bar(date_rainfall,rainfall,color='blue',label='Precipitation')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('Precipitation[mm]')
matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()

ax=fig.add_subplot(312)
ax.plot(date,discharge,color='red',label='discharge')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('discharge[m3/s]')
matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()

ax=fig.add_subplot(313)
ax.plot(date_stage,stage,color='green',label='stageheight')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('stageheight[m]')
matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel('Hours')

fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate() #rotates dates in xaxis
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is a shared xAxis
There you should add subplots in another way. 
I usually do that similar to the subplots_demo.py which you can find here:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html